# WP plugin With React JSX

Tags: php, wordpress, reactjs

I have created a React application which off course has JSX in it. Inside JSX I have an `img` tag. The `src` attribute is `"ïmg/image.png"`. When I am run this app in a browser it's using the correct path.

But when I am trying to load it inside a WP plugin it's taking the path from WP-admin. Which seems correct, but I have images inside my plugin folder. 
I can't make changes in the React code, because it is a generic app for which suppose to run on other CMS as well.
i am using this PHP hook:

```
add_action( "admin_print_scripts-$mypage", 'loadjscss_admin_head')

function loadjscss_admin_head() {
    global $plugindir;
    $plugindir = get_option('home').'/wp-content/plugins/'.dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_script('loadjs', $plugindir . '/jquery.js', array(), null);
    wp_enqueue_script('loadjs3', plugins_url('/bundle.js',__FILE__), array('loadjs'), null);
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why can't you compile the JSX to JS? You shouldn't be using JSX in production anyways...

Comment: I have compiled  js.But the problem is with image src . which is WP-admin/images/image.png . But image is inside wp-plugin/plugingFolder/image/image.png. The problem is not in react part

Comment: There is a dedicated StackExchange site for WordPress: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's also not clear why you tagged this with React and JSX as this isn't a problem with either (apparently).

Comment: wp_enqueue_script( 'loadjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bundle.js', array('jquery') );